# Getting CORS error in Firefox for WCF POST REST request

Tags: ajax, wcf, post

I am getting CORS error in Firefox for WCF POST request. This code is working fine in Edge, and Chrome. The error is seen only in Firefox. Furthermore the error is seen in Firefox only when I make a call with data parameter set and contentType set to "Application/Json; charset=utf-8". If change the contentType to "text/plain" I get "400 bad request" error. My code is as follows :

OPTIONS Heaer in WCF:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    public void GetOptions()
    {
        if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:5001");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,DELETE");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }
```

The post method Im calling:

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetAttachmentsPost1", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
    public void GetAttachmentsPost1( teststr teststr1)
    {

        string  str = "abc";

    }
[DataContract]
  public class teststr
{ 
[DataMember]
public string teststr1 { get; set; }
```

}

The AJAX call to the service:

```
 $.ajax({

            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5555/MyWCFService/GetAttachmentsPost1",

            type: "POST",

            data: JSON.stringify({ 'teststr1':'abc'} ),

            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "JSON",
            processData: true,
            error: function (data) {

            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    //     page not found
                }
            },
            complete: function (data) {

            },
        });
```

As I mentioned above that it works fine in Edge and Chrome, but only failing in FF. In Edge and Chrome preflight call is made to OPTIONS, but in FF the call is not going.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: In Firefox : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5555/MyWCFService/GetAttachmentsPost1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Firefox is not showing any call for this in Network pane. This seems to be failing in the preflight check. If I do not pass the - data: JSON.stringify({ 'teststr1':'abc'} ), param , remove the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", then call passes and it hits the WCF method.

Comment: Interestingly if in a POST request in Firefox I pass the data as query string like : 127.0.0.1:5555/MyWCFService/GetAttachmentsPost1?data=data, then it works. But if I pass the data as parameter data : data , as we do POST request, it fails!

Comment: This issue was happening for Firefox because my Web App is HTTPS while my WCF service is HTTP. For Firefox it  is a CORS issue : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

The solution lies in running WCF service also on https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happening for Firefox because my Web App is HTTPS while my WCF service is HTTP. For Firefox it  is a CORS issue : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

The solution lies in running WCF service also on https.